# Statistical Anomaly Detection with machine learning applications to IDS

Tags: anomaly-detection

as the topic says I am interested in learning more about anomaly detection in particular I am asking for good starting points and references both from a theoretical point of view and applied one. For the second one (applied) I am interested in tools to use and good "traffic packets sets" which I can use to start digging this area of information security.
You can assume I really don't know much about IDS and ML but I do have a good enough background in statistics and math.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly-based_intrusion_detection_system) is a bit of a stub, but has a couple of references to start with.

Theoretical issues with ML based IDSs are that they can be fooled in a number of ways, for example by forcing them to mis-train as in [this article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~shobha/research/ndss08-cr3-shobha.pdf). Think of this attack as what spammers do to confuse Bayesian filters.

A huge practical issue is that this approach is *extremely* slow for modern network speeds. The amount of processing that has to happen for every packet is probably going to grind such an IDS to a halt on a few Mbps.

Traffic packet sets are hard to find. There is this very old one http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/ that used to be popular. There is also http://www.netresec.com/?page=PcapFiles.